# Primefaces dataTable column width , color scheme , checkboxes functionality

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, facelets

I am new to primefaces and jsf and facing a few problems using it.

Following is the code i am using in jsf

```
<p:dataTable id="plazaId" var="plaza" value="#{coverageBean.plazaDataModel}" selection="#{coverageBean.selectedPlaza}" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
            <p:column id="name" headerText="Select" selectionMode="multiple"
                    style="width:18px" />
            <p:column id="plazaName" headerText="Plaza's" style="width: 50%"  bgcolor="#dcdcdc">
                <h:outputText value="#{plaza.name}" bgcolor="#dcdcdc"></h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            <p:column id="plazaDirect" headerText="Directo" style="width: 10%"  bgcolor="#dcdcdc">
                <h:outputText value="#{plaza.direct}" bgcolor="#dcdcdc"></h:outputText>
            </p:column>
          </p:dataTable>
```

I have checked the Beans and backend. They are all correct.

The issues are :

- I like to change the width using percentage in this table . But its not working.
- I like all the rows to be of the same color. But its showing alternate colors (white and blue)
- And is there a way to make the checkbox of simple html style . But its a little fancy.

Could anyone help with any of there problems. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't use `[xhtml]` tag for Facelets. The `[xhtml]` tag is too generic. I edited the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As of today, this is not possible. Refer to http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=2801
2. It is to do with styling. Define style as required.
3. It is to do with styling. Define style as required.

Comment: It should be noted that the bug that rags listed above applies to **scrollable** dataTables.  Percentage width should work fine with a regular dataTable.

Answer (score 3):

> I like to change the width using percentage in this table . But its not working.

You have syntax issues with your JSF view.  Their is no `bgcolor` attribute of `h:outputText`, this is a style attribute.

```
<h:outputText value="#{plaza.name}" headerText="Plazas" style="bgcolor: #dcdcdc;" />
```

This is also true for the `p:column` component as well...

```
<p:column id="plazaName" headerText="Plaza's" style="width: 50%; bgcolor: #dcdcdc;">
```

This also should fix your background color issue.

> And is there a way to make the checkbox of simple html style . But its a little fancy.

This would actually be quite difficult to do.  The `p:selectBooleanCheckbox` is really a styled div with javascript events attached to it.  Within this div is a hidden `input type="checkbox"` that exists as the form element that gets posted back.  You can't do this without tinkering with javascript and stylesheets that I know of.

Comment: Wrt the checkbox, just use `h:selectBooleanCheckbox`. Works as good.